# Can't turn `Solve` single-line list into multi-line `Table`

Tags: equation-solving, table

I am using the following code to calculate the two primes `{a,b}` closest to `n` which sum to `2n` (with `n` a natural number). Plug a value for `n` into `Module` and it spits out a one-line list of `{2n,a,b,b-a}`:

```
Module[
 {n = 13},
 {2*n,
 Last[a /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && 
   Element[b, Primes] && b - a > 0]],
 Last[b /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && Element[b, Primes] && b - a > 0]],
 (Last[b /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && Element[b, Primes] && 
     b - a > 0]] - Last[a /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && 
     Element[b, Primes] && b - a > 0]])/2}
]
```

> {26, 7, 19, 6}

But say I want to create a `Table` of these results for `{n,1,m}`, for some large number `m`. (Here, I have set `m` equal to `3` just for demonstration purposes.) I remove `Module` and write

```
Table[
 {2*n,
 Last[a /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && Element[b, Primes] && 
   b - a > 0]],
 Last[b /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && 
   Element[b, Primes] && b - a > 0]], 
 (Last[b /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && Element[b, Primes] && 
     b - a > 0]] - Last[a /. Solve[a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && 
     Element[b, Primes] && b - a > 0]])/2},
 {n, 1, 3}
]
```

But it doesn't work:

> Last::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Last[a].

> Last::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Last[b].

> Last::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Last[b].

> General::stop: Further output of Last::normal will be suppressed
> during this calculation.

> {{2, Last[a], Last[b], 1/2 (-Last[a] +
> Last[b])}, {4, Last[a],    Last[b], 1/2 (-Last[a] + Last[b])}, {6,
> Last[a], Last[b],    1/2 (-Last[a] + Last[b])}}

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors come from the lack of solutions in the case of small `n` because `Last` fails on the return value of `Solve` in those cases (i.e. the empty list `{}`, from which a last element cannot be extracted). You can use [the two-argument syntax of `Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html) to pass through the empty list in those cases, instead of throwing an error.

You also definitely do not need to run an identical `Solve` command three times to extract different portions of its output each time.

Putting those ideas together:

```
Table[
  ReplaceAll[
    {2 n, a, b, (b - a)/2},
    Last[
      Solve[
        a + b == 2*n && Element[a, Primes] && Element[b, Primes] && b - a > 0
      ],
      {} (* if there is no last part, then return {} *)
    ]
  ],
  {n, 1, 20}
]
```

This returns essentially unevaluated expressions when there is no solution, and the numerical values when solutions are found:

```
{
 {2, a, b, 1/2 (-a + b)}, {4, a, b, 1/2 (-a + b)},
 {6, a, b, 1/2 (-a + b)}, {8, 3, 5, 1}, 
 {10, 3, 7, 2}, {12, 5, 7, 1}, 
 {14, 3, 11, 4}, {16, 5, 11, 3},
 {18, 7, 11, 2}, {20, 7, 13, 3},
 {22, 5, 17, 6}, {24, 11, 13, 1},
 {26, 7, 19, 6}, {28, 11, 17, 3},
 {30, 13, 17, 2}, {32, 13, 19, 3},
 {34, 11, 23, 6}, {36, 17, 19, 1}, 
 {38, 7, 31, 12}, {40, 17, 23, 3}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. Much appreciated - I'd never have got there!

Comment: @Richard Glad I could help!